# Identification of a tropical fish with saw-like dorsal fin?

Tags: fish, fish-identification

[image: tropical fresh water fish]

Today, I went fishing in a local water reservoir with my younger siblings. We wanted to see if this man-made fresh water lake would have any fish. We live on a tropical island in the Southwestern Pacific. Do you have any idea what type of fish this is?

Fish specs:

• 7 inches long

• firm gill flap

• long anal fin

• dark greenish-gray color

• lives in shallow, fresh water

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This appears to be a

### Tilapia sparrmanii

Pictures:

[image: Tilapia 1]
[image: Tilapia 2]

Brief description:

> Tilapia sparrmanii, the banded tilapia, or vlei kurper, is a
>   widespread and adaptable cichlid fish that is found in warmer
>   freshwater habitats of southern Africa. They prefer water with ample
>   plant cover, and occur naturally as far north as DR Congo and
>   Tanzania. They have been introduced locally in the northern
>   hemisphere. Younger banded tilapia feed on crustaceans and insect
>   larvae, while the adults feed on terrestrial and aquatic plants and
>   other debris. They undertake local migrations and may shoal before and
>   during spawning time. They guard their own eggs, and although they may
>   move eggs or fry in the mouth, they are not known to be actual
>   mouthbrooders like several other tilapia species. This species can
>   reach a length of 23.5 centimetres (9.3 in) TL and is an important
>   foodfish.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilapia_sparrmanii)

### The fish is invasive in Micronesia

The fish was introduced to Micronesia for aquaculture in 1970. Check out [this site](http://www.fao.org/docrep/007/y5728e/y5728e04.htm) for reference and to read more about the introduction.

> As reported in Welcomme (1988) aquaculture was the prime reason for
>   the introductions of tilapias (Table 1). For the vast majority of the
>   records in DIAS there has been no evaluation of the ecological or
>   social/economic impact of the introduction (DIAS - Figure A). However,
>   of the impacts assessed, there were more positive social and economic
>   impacts reported than negative environmental impacts. Although
>   Welcomme (1988) and others (Beverton 1992) reported that the majority
>   of introductions did not result in the establishment of alien species
>   in the wild, the records in DIAS indicated that most tilapia
>   introductions to Asia and the Pacific were successful at establishing
>   reproducing populations (DIAS - Figure B).
>
> Of the species introduced to Asia, O. mossambicus and O. niloticus are
>   by far the most important from both production and scientific points
>   of view. These species are now widely distributed in most of Asia and
>   occur in natural and quasi-natural waters making them a part of the
>   fish fauna of most of tropical and even sub-tropical Asian aquatic
>   environments, thus creating an increased concern among some
>   conservationists and environmental lobby groups (Pethiyagoda, 1994).
>   Tilapia species tend to hybridize relatively easily, a trait that had
>   been utilized in tilapia aquaculture development from the very early
>   stages (Hickling, 1960; 1963). Introgressive hybridization in cultured
>   stocks (Macaranas et al., 1986) and self-recruiting stocks (De Silva
>   and Ranasinghe, 1989) of tilapia species, particularly between O.
>   mossambicus and O. niloticus, have been reported from many countries.
>   The "red tilapia", a hybrid between strains of O. mossambicus x O.
>   niloticus is currently considered as important to aquaculture in Asia
>   (Welcomme and Vidthayanon 1999).